# MySQL query to find hour of the day when the number of housing society visits is highest

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

Housing Society Visit Data

| Id | Contact | Entry_time | Exit_time | Duration of Stay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8080808080 | 26/07/2021 08:00:05 | 26/07/2021 08:23:06 | 181 |
| 2 | 9692596925 | 26/07/2021 08:12:49 | 26/07/2021 08:14:44 | 115 |
| 3 | 7099270992 | 26/07/2021 11:02:49 | 26/07/2021 11:14:44 | 715 |
| 4 | 8900289002 | 26/07/2021 16:12:49 | 26/07/2021 16:14:44 | 115 |
| 5 | 9089590895 | 26/07/2021 15:12:49 | 26/07/2021 15:14:44 | 115 |
| 6 | 8765087650 | 26/07/2021 19:12:49 | 26/07/2021 19:14:44 | 115 |
| 7 | 7862178621 | 26/07/2021 18:12:49 | 26/07/2021 18:14:44 | 115 |

Visit data is available for many years and can contain millions of rows, so the solution should have a low time complexity.
Expected output: **8-9 AM** (since highest number of visits (2) are made during that hour).

Comment: What have you tried, with which results and with what expected outcome?

Comment: What if a visit last 3 hours should all 3 hours be included in separate hour counts?

Comment: Edit the question and post the data as text not as image, so it can be easier to reproduce the problem

Comment: @Firewizz I have updated the expected output.

Comment: @P.Salmon No I just need the hour with the maximum occurrences.

Comment: @ErgestBasha I have removed the image of the table and added the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the required output using the following query:
SELECT HOUR(Entry_time) as hr FROM table_name GROUP BY HOUR(Entry_time) ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1;
Thanks to the solution by @nicholascarey: [SQL to determine peak volume and hour for all days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223109/sql-to-determine-peak-volume-and-hour-for-all-days)

Answer (score 0):

As I read the question this would help you very much on the way.
There are a couple of things you can do to improve this tho:

- Create separate table with hours to avoid the unions (or do it with numbers table);
- Store times separatly, the TIME() method slows the query.

.

```
SELECT 
    hours.`hour`,
    COUNT(occurrence.perfId) AS occurrences
FROM (
    SELECT '00:00' AS `hour`
    UNION SELECT '01:00'
    UNION SELECT '02:00'
    UNION SELECT '03:00'
    UNION SELECT '04:00'
    UNION SELECT '05:00'
    UNION SELECT '06:00'
    UNION SELECT '07:00'
    UNION SELECT '08:00'
    UNION SELECT '09:00'
    UNION SELECT '10:00'
    UNION SELECT '11:00'
    UNION SELECT '12:00'
    UNION SELECT '13:00'
    UNION SELECT '14:00'
    UNION SELECT '15:00'
    UNION SELECT '16:00'
    UNION SELECT '17:00'
    UNION SELECT '18:00'
    UNION SELECT '19:00'
    UNION SELECT '20:00'
    UNION SELECT '21:00'
    UNION SELECT '22:00'
    UNION SELECT '23:00'    
) hours
LEFT JOIN YOUR_TABLE occurrence ON hours.`hour` BETWEEN TIME(occurrence.Entry_time) AND TIME(occurrence.Exit_time)
GROUP BY hours.`hour`
ORDER BY occurrences DESC
```

Would produce (Data from a test database):

```
[hour] [occurrences]
10:00   73554
11:00   67492
09:00   65679
08:00   63886
13:00   63565
12:00   62525
07:00   61500
14:00   53095
15:00   49017
16:00   41955
17:00   31991
18:00   21251
06:00   17591
19:00   13717
20:00   8532
21:00   4421
22:00   2050
23:00   818
05:00   796
04:00   561
01:00   175
03:00   123
02:00   120
00:00   23
```

To get the hour only just wrap with a query and select the first:

```
SELECT hour FROM (
    # Paste query from above here...
) hourData
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Noted. But for the time being, can you just help me with this table? Also, I just need the hour with the maximum occurrences (not the count of occurrences) to be printed as the output which is 8-9AM for my table.

Comment: You mean maximum occurances per day or??

Comment: Not per day, I need maximum occurrences from the entire table.

Comment: But tell me if I am wrong but isn't the count exactly the number of occurrences?

Comment: yes, you are correct.